# What happens after beta?

Tags: support, area-51

Will the site be removed from area51, or get a special place somewhere?

Comment: A comprehensive list of public stack exchange sites would be a good thing. Perhaps once some sites go public that is what www.stackexchange.com will become.

Comment: @simon: I had that great idea, but then it just got eaten by the page after page of questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56362/so-needs-a-big-master-list-of-sites

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping to create some sort of Corporate or SE Network-wide site that would include a catalog of Stack Exchange sites. The stackexchange.com home page is all-but unused. When the number of Stack Exchange sites reaches in the hundreds (or thousands), I'm not sure it makes sense to list full-fledged sites with Proposals.

I'm not saying this *is* the way its going to be done. But it's on my personal road map.