# Master website list suggestions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

So I see that there is finally a [master list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) that I [suggested a while ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56362/so-needs-a-big-master-list-of-sites) (thanks!), but I just thought I might give some suggestions on how it could be improved. Since the `status-completed` tag was added 20 hours ago I might be just saying things that might be implemented soon, but I just want to get all of them out

- **Link it in the FAQ** - Maybe after the initial list of obvious alternatives, why not say

  > - Subject not listed? Try the [Site Directory](https://stackexchange.com/sites) to find the best site.

  Lack of mentioning this will just give us the origional problem of people not knowing other sites exist.
- **Give it a link at the bottom of the page** - This might be an issue, as space is already short. But would a small [`More...`](https://stackexchange.com/sites) link work?
- **List stackapps, SO Careers, Area 51, and DocType** (sister section perhaps?). They are all worthy of mention
- **Put Meta's next to site, as well as an explanation of meta at the bottom** - This would be something useful, as right now most people don't know what Meta is
- **Put chat next to SO** - Why not? Need to be registered and have reputation anyway
- **Give it an RSS feed** - What would be the quickest way to spread the word that a new site is out? RSS! If you have hundreds of people subscribe, and a beta for Military Hardware is created, you now have tons of new people! And now your not relying solely on people that constantly follow Area 51 (IE me, because I can only commit to 3 things, and such things take a while, and the notifications are a little spammy). The half an hour of writing a RSS feed would tremendously help out any new site.

Just some suggestions. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe many of these are completed, including

- linking to /sites in the faq
- a rss feed for the site list

.. any other thoughts?

Comment: Wow, I think that just about covers it. Adding meta and chat to the bottom would eat too much space now that I look at it.

Comment: @thelq any thoughts on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87239/suggest-the-next-feature-for-stackexchange-com ?