# Does the Community user bump 'status-completed' questions as well?

Tags: support, tags, community-user, bump

Two days back I saw an *ancient* meta question on  some stack - don't remember the exact one - and it was a 'status completed' question. The asker themselves then added an answer and accepted it writing something along the lines of "in order to avoid getting bumped by the Community user".

Does the Community user bump questions with 'status-completed' tags in case there's no upvoted answer?

If it does, would it be necessary to make an exception to questions tagged that way from getting bumped? Not that I think that's a problem or priority - but curious nonetheless.

Comment: I think it does, and the rationale is (iirc) to encourage always posting an answer instead of just slapping a status tag on it.

Comment: @Stijn It must have been that way. But has it changed?

Comment: Actually that user did exactly the opposite: without any answer, the question will never be auto bumped. By adding that answer the user caused the system to auto bump the question over and over as long as the answer has no upvotes. Worth telling them that. (Probably the OP got confused between the auto bump feature and the Unanswered Questions tab)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks. I figured that out, in my now-deleted answer here.

Comment: I don't think tags, even super special tags have any role in the bumping process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Community user definitely does bump these questions. I've found one on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/354278/revisions) that has a zero-score answer and a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag but was bumped by Community after the tag was added.

I haven't looked through them all but using the [following search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstatus-completed%5D%20isanswered%3A0%20answers%3A1), you should be able to find more of them on any meta site you like:

> [status-completed] isanswered:0 answers:1

This returns questions with the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag, questions that, by the system's definitions are not answered (have no answers with a score greater than 0) and do have at least one answer.

An added caveat is that if an answer is *accepted* it isn't bumped by community. As an example, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56362/so-needs-a-big-master-list-of-sites). So, to filter these out of your search results, you can add "hasaccepted:no" to your search terms. This leaves [only 35 questions on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstatus-completed%5D%20isanswered%3A0%20answers%3A1%20hasaccepted%3Ano), actually (down from 200). A short enough list to look through.

You can further [drop this number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstatus-completed%5D%20isanswered%3A0%20answers%3A1%20hasaccepted%3Ano%20closed%3Ano) to 10 by adding "closed:no"... making me wonder if this is really a big enough concern to be worried about. Of these ten questions, none of them qualify to be bumped by Community as all of the answers have negative scores.

Now, some sites may use the status tags more than MSE... but I'm guessing not. Even MSO only has 9 questions that meet the final search:

> [status-completed] isanswered:0 answers:1 hasaccepted:no closed:no

I suppose it's possible that I've erred in my search terms, so I'm happy to be corrected if I've done so.

Comment: Should be `answers:1..` because a question with multiple answers may be bumped (if one of them scored 0 and none score more than 0, subject to other conditions you mentioned)

Comment: But "answers:1" means all questions with 1 **or more** answers. Both versions return the same results.

Comment: I have updated the question a little bit. Now your answer is complete.

Answer (score 3):

As Catija points out, they are still bumped.

As for your last point... There's not really any reason for a status tag to prevent a question being bumped. The whole point of bumping a question is to review *answers* to that question, not the question itself. As the "bumped to the homepage" notice says:

> **This question has answers that may be good or bad**; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.

Just because a feature has been implemented or a bug fixed or whatever it is has been "completed" shouldn't really exclude any answers that slipped through from being reviewed.